# The onResume method causes Activity to crash

Tags: android, onresume

I am overriding onResume method to load previos state of my activity where it was ie spinner's last selected item etc. However the same code works fine for some activities but for some it causes crash as when i remove this onResume from them, Activity doesnt crash.

Here's the code

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        sp4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        sp5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

TextView tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.upgradeResult) ;
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("restore_defensiveBuildings_state", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int spinner1Indx = prefs.getInt("spinner1_indx", 0);
        int spinner2Indx = prefs.getInt("spinner2_indx", 0);
        int spinner3Indx = prefs.getInt("spinner3_indx", 0);
        int spinner4Indx = prefs.getInt("spinner4_indx", 0);
        int spinner5Indx = prefs.getInt("spinner5_indx", 0);


        sp1.setSelection(spinner1Indx);
        sp2.setSelection(spinner2Indx);
        sp3.setSelection(spinner3Indx);
        sp4.setSelection(spinner4Indx);
        sp5.setSelection(spinner5Indx);


        tx.setText(""+totalAirBombUpgradeCost);
    }
```

This is how i loaded items to the adapter

```
     Spinner sp1;
        Spinner sp2;
        Spinner sp3;
        Spinner sp4;
        Spinner sp5;

        TextView tx;
        Button sbmt;
    String levels[]={"Level 1",
            "Level 2",
            "Level 3",
            "Level 4"

           };

        int[] images={R.drawable.giant_bomb_1and2,
                R.drawable.giant_bomb_1and2 ,
                R.drawable.giant_bomb_3and4,
                R.drawable.giant_bomb_3and4


                };

 @Override
       protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giant_bomb);


//// initialize all your visual fields
//          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
//              sp1.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("MySpinner1", 0));
//              // do this for each of your text views
//          }



sbmt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.upgradeResult);
        sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(spinner);
        sp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
          sp3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
          sp4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
          sp5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);


        SpinnerAdapterGiant adapter=new SpinnerAdapterGiant(this,levels,images);



          sp1.setAdapter(adapter);

        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
          sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
          sp4.setAdapter(adapter);
          sp5.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is the error

```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
```

EDIT: When i remove onResume(), everything works fine app doesn't crash, just that it doesn't load activity's previous state.

Comment: because You have only 4 elements in your list. Array always start from 0. in your case array elements you can ace's 0 to 3. 4th index is not existing in your array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: i am adding 4 items to each spinner @SaurabhBhandari

Comment: One of your `spinnerXIndx` is set to 4. As all collection based objects are zero-based, an object with 4 items will have indices 0,1,2 & 3. 4 is out of bounds in this case. Please verify that none of the `spinnerXIndx` variables is not greater than 3

Comment: and how would i check spinnerXIndx variable? @0xDEADC0DE

Comment: Debugging or add logging

Answer (score 0):

Because in array you put only 4 value and there 5 spinner so in 5th spinner error occur.

Comment: i am adding 4 items to each of the 5 spinners, check out the edit how i initialized my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to access the 5th element in an array of size 4. Your levels and images array have only for element but you have 5 spinners
Increase your array size to 5.

Comment: i am adding 4 items to each of the 5 spinners, check out the edit how i initialized my adapter.